# Definition: Tower of Rings

Tags: ring-theory, homological-algebra

This should be a remarkably easy question, but one which I am curiously finding myself unable to find a formal definition of on the internets: is a tower of rings simply defined in the same way as that a tower of fields, i.e., if $R$ is a subring of $S$, which in turn is a subring of $T$, then $R \subseteq S \subseteq T$ is a tower of rings?

The reason why I am asking this question is because Weibel in his book on $K$-theory at one point mentions "the tower of rings $R/I^n$", but, well, it is not necessarily the case that given an ideal $I$ of a ring $R$ that $R/I$ is isomorphic to a subring of $R$. Further, while one can of course construct surjections such that we have a sequence
$$R \twoheadrightarrow R/I \twoheadrightarrow R/I^2 \twoheadrightarrow R/I^3 \twoheadrightarrow R/I^4 \twoheadrightarrow \dots \twoheadrightarrow R/I^k \twoheadrightarrow R/I^{k+1} \twoheadrightarrow \dots$$
those are surjections, not injections. I furthermore on Wikipedia learn that the formal definition of a **[ring extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_extension)** appears to be a bit more sophisticated than that of a mere field extension. Which makes me wonder, maybe the formal definition of a power of rings has something to do with how a long exact sequence can be thought of as a succession of short exact sequences.

Would very much appreciate to have this sorted out, thank you.

Comment: Note, your maps are going the wrong way $(R/I \twoheadleftarrow R/I^2 \twoheadleftarrow R/I^3 \dots)$

Comment: I am? Oh, right. The natural surjection $R/I^2 \twoheadrightarrow R/I$ is defined by $r+I^2 \mapsto r+I$ since every $i \in I^2$ obviously is also an element of $I$, making it all well-defined. The only surjection you cannot do is $R/I \twoheadrightarrow R$.